# Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, dictionary, byte, serializable

A function is returning a dictionary, which has data of type byte. Because it's inside, it gave a dictionary, I couldn't do a simple conversion, using

```
value.decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

I would need to go through the entire dictionary and its internal data certifying the data type to overwrite it with the decode.
To simulate, I left an example code that returns the same error:

```
import json

dictionary ={ 
  "id": "04", 
  "name": "sunil", 
  "code": b"HR"
} 
      
json_object = json.dumps(dictionary, indent = 4) 
print(json_object)
```

I would like to convert this internal byte data inside a dictionary into some str, so that I could generate the json .

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

dictionary ={ 
  "id": "04", 
  "name": "sunil", 
  "code": b"HR".decode('UTF-8')
} 
      
json_object = json.dumps(dictionary, indent = 4) 
print(type(json_object))
```

Not sure if your dict had a error in it? But if not try this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this recursive function.

```
def decodeDictionary(dictionary):
    if type(dictionary) == dict:
        for key in dictionary.keys():
            dictionary[key] = decodeDictionary(dictionary[key])
    elif type(dictionary[key]) == bytes:
        dictionary = dictionary.decode('ISO-8859-1') 
    return dictionary
```